# jquery - disable click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to disable the ability for a user to click on an element for some condition.  Here is some of the code I am working with:

```
     $('#navigation a').bind('click',function(e){

    var $this   = $(this);
    var prev    = current;

    current = $this.parent().index() + 1; // store the position in current

    if (current == 1){
    $("#navigation a:eq(1)").unbind("click"); // i want to disable the ability to click this element if current is 1
    }
    if (current >= 2){
    $("#navigation a:eq(1)").bind("click"); // this is wrong, but I want to rebind the click if current is greater than 1.  
    }
```

}

Comment: `$('selector').prop("disabled", true);`

Answer (score 104, accepted):

If you're using jQuery versions 1.4.3+:

```
$('selector').click(false);
```

If not:

```
$('selector').click(function(){return false;});
```

Comment: Is there a way to toggle disabling the click function instead of redefining it?

Answer (score 27):

assuming your using click events, just unbind that one.

example

```
if (current = 1){ 
    $('li:eq(2)').unbind("click");
}
```

EDIT:
Are you currently binding a click event to your list somewhere?  Based on your comment above, I'm wondering if this is really what you're doing?  How are you enabling the click? Is it just an anchor(`<a>` tag) ?  A little more explicit information will help us answer your question.

UPDATE:

Did some playing around with the :eq() operator. http://jsfiddle.net/ehudokai/VRGfS/5/

As I should have expected it is a 0 based index operator.  So if you want to turn of the second element in your selection, where your selection is

```
$("#navigation a")
```

you would simply add :eq(1) (the second index) and then .unbind("click")  So:

```
if(current == 1){
    $("#navigation a:eq(1)").unbind("click");
}
```

Ought to do the trick.

Hope this helps!

Comment: im binding the click in a manner like this:  $('#navigation a').bind('click',function(e){    so i am using the <a> tag.

Comment: Oh, ok, that helps a lot.  It's really just as simple as adding the a onto the selector I think. So:  $('#navigation li:eq(2) a').unbind('click');

Comment: @scifirocket: Of course I was wrong, but if you see my update above, I tested this answer :).

Comment: so now that I have unbinded the click if current = 1, how can I rebind the click otherwise.  I know it's not as simple as $("#navigation a:eq(1)").bind("click");

Comment: to rebind do `$("#navigation a:eq(1)").bind("click", function(){//yourcode});`

Answer (score 10):

Raw Javascript can accomplish the same thing pretty quickly also:

```
document.getElementById("myElement").onclick = function() { return false; }
```

Comment: I assumed that it was a typo, so I added the "#" to the jQuery selector ;)

Comment: Although... the `.onclick` won't work on a jQuery object either. You need `[0]` or `.get(0)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use unbind method to remove handler that has been attached...

```
if (current = 1){ 
   $('li:eq(2)').unbind('click');
}
```

You can check what can unbind do ? [Unbind manual](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Comment: actually, I probably needed to use something like this" $('#navigation li:eq(2)').unbind('click');    but that isn't working either.  im trying to disable the click event to a particular element of a list.

Comment: @scifirocket: are you binding a click event somewhere in your code?  Or are you just using an anchor that you want to disable?

Answer (score 2):

Use `off()` method after click event is triggered to disable element for the further click.

```
$('#clickElement').off('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

/** eworkyou **//

```
$('#navigation a').bind('click',function(e){

    var $this   = $(this);
    var prev    = current;

    current = $this.parent().index() + 1; //

    if (current == 1){
    $("#navigation a:eq(1)").unbind("click"); // 
    }
    if (current >= 2){
    $("#navigation a:eq(1)").bind("click"); // 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used .prop('disabled', true) and it worked like a charm, no redefining, simple.

Had to time it out by 125ms as it interfered with the prop from Bootstrap Dropdown.