# How prevent click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery - disable click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589964/jquery-disable-click)

How can I prevent a click event of a button's selector when is pushed? If there are some buttons. I want to lock the event of the button pushed. I have tried  with:

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
event.stopPropagation(); 
event.preventDefault();
```

But it does not work.

Edit: I haven't provided the code because is backbone code and this isn't a theme of that theme. If I have a list of buttons in a menu, and I press one multiple times, the code associated a that button is run multiple times. I want to lock this click event and unlock it if other button is pushed.

Solution:

```
//disable
$("#button").bind('click', function() { return false; });

//enable
$("#button").unbind('click');
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or show a complete code example?

Comment: Make sure event object is passed to the handler function like -- `.on('click', function(event) { `

Comment: Please provide a code example.

Comment: Those will work.  You're doing something else wrong.  Show us some code.

Comment: Try returning `false` in the event handler function?

Comment: What does "but not work" mean? What errors do you get? What does your HTML look like? How about a jsFiddle example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589964/jquery-disable-click

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: I haven't provided the code because is backbone code and this isn't a theme of that theme. If I have a list of buttons in a menu, and I press one multiple times, the code associated a that button is run multiple times. I want to lock this click event and unlock it if other button is pushed. (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a return `false` in your jQuery handler

```
$("#button").click( function () {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: The example works, the click event of "#button" locks it but how can I unlock it? And how unlock all buttons?

Comment: Hello @Wolf. Thanks for response, but how can I return it the previous state?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by previous state...

Comment: I use backbone.js framework, when click event is run, other function is run and your code also. Then, the click event is disabled. How return to enable it?

Comment: I have the solution. I have edited the question