# how to disable or ignore a click() event

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I've made a card surrounding with an anchor tag and applied a onclick() event on the card using it's id, the click is working fine but the problem here is even if the `checkbox, image or button` of card gets clicked the click event of the card fires up but I've to use the `checkbox and button` for another purpose, so is there any way to disable or ignore the click event of the card when the checkbox or the button gets clicked

HTML:

```
<div id="row" id"myDiv">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card card2"
                style="margin-bottom: 0.5rem !important;"
                id="btnQuoteSummary">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-9"></div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkSelect"
                            id="checkSelect1"><label for="checkSelect1"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <span class="float-left"><img
                            class="card-img-top insLogo"
                            style="width: 5rem; object-fit: contain;"
                            src="/static/images/86d5b04c-1201-4ef4-b0e8-88503c719e2b.jpg"
                            alt="my image"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4"></div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="min-width-zero">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">
                            <span>3,954</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8">
                    <p class="mb-2 text-muted" style="margin-left: 4.5rem;">value</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <p class="mb-2 text-muted">4.35</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#myDiv').on('click', '#btnQuoteSummary', function () {
    alert('card click event fired')
});
```

Please help me here

Comment: Where is `myDiv` and `btnQuoteSummary` ?

Comment: use `preventDefault()`

Comment: @Ibnelaiq appreciate your help but it'll easy for me if you provide me a demonstration or give a link of the source as I'm still a learner

Comment: @ascsoftw have a look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061254/ignore-parent-onclick-event-when-child-element-is-clicked/26098731 [possible duplicate]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery - disable click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589964/jquery-disable-click)

Comment: `$("#block a").click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });`

Comment: @Cybertronian May be that is because you have included all the in the `<a>` tag.  Can you try to put your image, checkbox or button in a separate div.

Comment: @AnshuSharma yup I've tried that too

Comment: @Cybertronian can you please show what have you tried ?

Comment: @AnshuSharma I've edited my question you can have a look

Comment: @Ibnelaiq and what if i want to add another click event on `#block a` from `$("#block a").click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });`

Comment: yes it will apply on both of them.Tell me if that work

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btnQuoteSummary').click(function(event){
        alert('card click event fired');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just off click event for that particular button-through following code,

```
$('#btnQuoteSummary').off('click');
```

This will work perfectly.

Comment: what if i want to set another function

Answer (score 0):

One option through. CSS

```
.avoid-clicks {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Or through jQuery:

```
$( "#btnQuoteSummary " ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting these lines in the click event of child elements to disable triggering the click event of parent element

```
if (!e) var e = window.event;
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
```

Eg:

```
 $("your-button-id / your-input-checkbox-id /your-img-id etc").click(function(){
    /*
    code to execute (if any)
    */
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
 });
```